# How to remove lines from a text file words in a list?

Tags: bash

file1 > word_list.txt > over 1,000,000 Lines

file2 > list.txt > over 1,000,000 Lines

I have a file containing a list of words. I want to remove all occurrences of all the words in this file from a big text file.

Example:

File 1

```
111
222
```

Text file sample

```
111
222
333
444
555
```

Output

```
333
444
555
```

This code be very slow for large files with over 1 million lines:

```
sed -e "$(sed 's:.*:s/&//ig:' word_list.txt)" list.txt
```

What is the most appropriate method for this problem?

Comment: Great first Q with sample data, required output and .... gasp, some code! Good show. I would assume you also need to NOT delete lines like `111222333` (for example, there are millions more. Using solution below, I would add edit your search target file to use line anchors , i.e. `^111$`, `^222$`, etc. Keep posting. Good luck.

Comment: very thanks bro , but File1 is big files over (100,000 words) cant use thats

Comment: Do you want to delete the words alone or the complete lines they happen to appear on?

Comment: i want delete  complete lines

Comment: @Cyrus, why you deleted your answer ? Even though it's not as fast as `comm` approach, `grep -vxf` is still very efficient.

Comment: how can remove line in word ?

Comment: `grep -Fvxf word_list.txt list.txt` would be better - uses a fast string matching algorithm instead of treating each line of `word_list.txt` as a regular expression.

Comment: @Shawn Agreed, with only numbers in both files, `-F` is 10% more performant. What I'm interested is comparing the complexities of `comm` and `grep` approaches. I understand the complexity of `grep` is O(n**2), so it should be significantly slower, but in my test, with 1 million entries in both files, the difference is roughly 1 second vs 3 seconds.

Comment: @Philippe Aho-Corasick isn't quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assumptions,
files are structured one word per each line, words are unique in each file, files can be sorted (or in sorted order already)

```
$ comm -13 file1 file2

333
444
555

-1   suppress lines unique to file1
-3   suppress lines that appear in both files
```

which will give you unique words in file2 which are not in file1 (that is set difference file2 \ file1)

This should be the fastest approach.  Please post the timings if you can test alternative solutions.

Alternatively,

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

should work as long as you have enough memory.  This doesn't require sorting.